# How to handle OverflowError: (34, 'Result too large') as a beginner?

Tags: python, decimal, integer-overflow

I am a relative beginner in python and I saw some similar content I understood something but not completely. I am a math student and I try to solve problems on project Euler. The question was finding the index of the first term in the Fibonacci sequence to contain 1000 digits. I find the general formula for the Fibonacci sequence and wrote it in python as below. It raises an error which is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\baldi\Desktop\soru.py", line 6, in <module>
    if int(log10(fib(i)))+1<1000:
  File "C:\Users\baldi\Desktop\soru.py", line 4, in fib
    return (((sqrt(5)+1)/sqrt(20))*((sqrt(5)+ 1)/2)**(n-1)+((sqrt(5)-1)/sqrt(20))*((-sqrt(5)+ 1)/2)**(n-1))
OverflowError: (34, 'Result too large')
```

and then I wanted to find after which I value my function doesn't respond.

```
from math import sqrt, log10
a = sqrt(5)
b= sqrt(20)

def fib(n):
    return (((a+1)/b)*((a+ 1)/2)**(n-1)+((a-1)/b)*((-a+1)/2)**(n-1))
for i in range(1,10**4):
    if int(log10(fib(i)))+1<1000:
        continue
    else:
        print(i)
        break
```

it said the computer cannot compute after i=1476. I read similar articles, they said you could use the decimal library, etc. But as beginner, I either don't know how to use them or I cannot understand the notation to learn them.  Can you please help me and please can it be not too complex?

Comment: Unfortunately, trying to calculate large Fibonacci numbers with that closed form will result in inaccuracies due to floating poing math.

Comment: @CrazyChucky correct me if I'm wrong but doesn't the decimal package exist precisely to solve this, i.e. to give you as much precision as you want?

Comment: One of the uses of solving Project Euler problems is to improve your understanding of math and programming. If you keep insisting on taking simple answers only, then you are defeating the purpose of Project Euler, and you will learn much less from this work of yours than you potentially could.

Comment: @yagod you're going to have to keep track of just how much precision you need in the input values in order to avoid rounding errors in the calculation (which can involve *very* large exponents), and figuring that out is a puzzle in and of itself. It's also the sort of thing that you won't know you've gotten wrong, unless you double-check with another method.

Answer (score 1):

To find the index of the first term in the Fibonacci sequence to contain 1000 digits using Python, you can use the following approach:

1. Define a function fibonacci_index that takes in a number n and
   returns the index of the first term in the Fibonacci sequence to
   contain n digits.
2. Initialize variables a and b to 1, which are the first two terms of
   the Fibonacci sequence.
3. Initialize a variable index to 2, which is the index of the second
   term in the sequence.
4. Implement a while loop that continues until the number of digits in
   a is greater than or equal to n. Inside the loop:

Calculate the next term in the Fibonacci sequence by adding a and b and
storing the result in a new variable c.
Set a to b and b to c.
Increment index by 1.
Return index after the while loop has been completed.
Here is the code that implements this approach:

```
def fibonacci_index(n):
    a, b = 1, 1
    index = 2
    while len(str(a)) < n:
        c = a + b
        a, b = b, c
        index += 1
    return index

print(fibonacci_index(1000))  # prints 4782
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your numbers are too large for python to handle. So what you want to do is

```
from decimal import Decimal
```

Then turn `a` and `b` into decimals:

```
a = Decimal(sqrt(5))
b = Decimal(sqrt(20))
```

Now we also need to ensure the index `i` is a Decimal. However, if we only changed that we would run into an error when trying to use math.log10. Instead, we use the log function included in the decimal package:

```
for i in range(1,10**4):
    if int(fib(Decimal(i)).log10())+1<1000:
        continue
    else:
        print(i)
        break
```

Comment: You probably want `round()` instead of `int()`; the latter will always round toward zero. Even then, using the asker's closed form and Python's default precision for the `Decimal` class appears to stop being accurate past only the seventieth Fibonacci number.

Comment: Huh. It also turns out that the *amount* by which each one is off increases in an approximation of the Fibonacci sequence, though it too gets less accurate as it goes. Fascinating.